# What is the meaning of const in this function signature?

Tags: c++, constants

Please help me understand the following signature:

```
err_type funcName(const Type& buffer) const;
```

For the first `const`, does that mean the contents of `Type` cannot change or that the reference cannot change?

Secondly, what does the second `const` mean?

Answer (score 18):

The second const means the method can be called on a const object.

Consider this example:

```
class foo
{
public:
    void const_method() const;
    void nonconst_method();
};

void doit()
{
    const foo f;

    f.const_method();      // this is okay
    f.nonconst_method();   // the compiler will not allow this
}
```

Furthermore, a const method is not allowed to change any members of the object (unless the member is specifically marked at mutable):

```
class foo
{
public:
    void const_method() const;

private:
    int r;
    mutable int m;
};

void foo::const_method() const
{
    m = 0; // this is okay as m is marked mutable
    r = 0; // the compiler will not allow this
}
```

Comment: And you should probably not have mutable members of your class.

Comment: Mutable members are very useful. The compiler only enforces bitwise constness -- meaning that the actual bits of the object can't change . However, if the logical state of the object is not affected by the change, the item should be declared mutable. For example, if I have an object that queries a database, it makes sense for a const object to allow select queries against itself. But it might need to modify, say, a "database_connection" object internally while running a function, which may be reused in other queries, In that case, `mutable` helps you maintain logical const -- a good thing.

Comment: In the book Financial instrument pricing using C++, I can see the second constant in normal function signatures, not class member methods. What does it mean then?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the first `const` means that `buffer` can not change.

The second `const` implies that this is a class' member function, and will not change the object (`this`).

Answer (score 4):

This will explain better than most of us probably can so I wont repeat:
 http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Answer (score 3):

Directly: It means the const applies to instances on which that method is called.  You may not call it on a non-const object.

**The const rule:** The const keyword modifies the thing to its *left*, unless there is nothing, in which case it modifies the thing to its right.

Thus, the type "const int" is a special case and means the same as "int const".

When you apply the rule to methods you get "<method> const".  (It's something of a stretch, but still helpful to understand this way.)

Other examples ("read from the inside-out"), where "id" is the identifier, but may be removed without changing the types:

- `int const* id` = pointer to constant int
- `int* const id` = constant pointer to int
- `int const id[5]` = array of 5x constant int
- `int (*const id)[5]` = constant pointer to array of 5x int

More commonly, `T const&` and `T const*` are used by some people, as it maintains consistency by not requiring a special case.  I additionally prefer it because the type at the start is often more helpful than knowing it's constant.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but it has a more significant meaning. It is a contract for your class that says "by calling this function, you will not change the state of your object". People interpret this differently, some view it as the object will not change in appearance to the caller, while others view it as the object will not change at all if you call this function.

Answer (score 0):

The first `const` is a gurantee that the function will not change `buffer`, and thus can be passed a const buffer.

The second `const` is only meaningful when used as a method for a class.  It is a gurantee that calling the method will not have any side effects on the class that contains the method.  Essentially a gurantee that this method can be safely called on `const` objects.

Comment: To be precise 'will not have any effects on the class that contains the method' should be reworded. A constant method can change static members of the class, what must remain unchanged is the instance on which the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

While you've gotten some good answers, I think it's worth pointing out that a class can contain `mutable` member variables. A `mutable` member is one that you're *always* allowed to modify, even when it's part of a const object. These are typically used for things like memoizing and caching, where the variable can be modified without affecting the user-visible state of the object as a whole.